# Unable to use alias name with powershell

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, cname-record, alias

I have created an CNAME alias record (PublicShare) for one of our servers (KWT-SRV01) in Windows Server DNS. Unfortunately i am unable to use it in powershell "-path" attribute. For example,

this works just fine

```
New-vm -ComputerName KUW-SRV04 -MemoryStartupBytes 1GB -NoVHD -Generation 2 -Name TEST123 -Path "\\KWT-SRV01\Test\"
```

but when using the Alias name, i get the following error

```
New-vm -ComputerName KUW-SRV04 -MemoryStartupBytes 1GB -NoVHD -Generation 2 -Name TEST123 -Path "\\Publicshare\Test\"
```

[New-VM : Failed to create a new virtual machine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDlbe.png)

What am i missing?

Note:

I am issuing the above commands from another separate server (KWT-SRV05)

Answer (score 2):

Please look here for Option 2
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/josebda/multiple-names-for-one-computer-consolidate-your-smb-file-servers-without-breaking-unc-paths

The problem is that client, when using Kerberos Auth (by default for domain shares) checks server for its name to avoid authenticating to wrong/fake server, and server responds with different name, because server does not know about alternative names.

> Client: Hey, Bob!
>
> Server: Hi, I am Alice.
>
> Client: Whoops, sorry!

After you apply secondary name:

> Client: Hey, Bob!
>
> Server: Hi, I am Alice, but friends call me Bob
>
> Client: Okay.....okay...

Actually this explanation is completely incorrect technically, but in fact this is better to understand like that, instead of deep diving into Kerberos.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately I came across this website last night and I applied option number 2 but without any luck. I also found this detailed article about the same issue. 

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/using-computer-name-aliases-in-place-of-dns-cname-records/ba-p/259064

I rebooted the server but i still get the same error.